# Execute function with name stored as a value in a dictionary

Tags: c#

I have created a dictionary, where funcDef is a name of a function. For example, some of the elements I add to my dictionary:

```
dict.Add("Banana", (a, b) => getNumberofBananas(a, b));
dict.Add("Apple", (a, b) => getNumberofApples(a, b));
```

Where getNumberofApples/Bananas are public functions implemented in the same class. I can get the function I need when I type

```
dict.Remove(string myKey)
```

But how can I call it to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to *remove* the element from your dictionary. You'll need to extract it from the dictionary and invoke it. Assuming your delegates are of type `Func<int, int, int>`:

If you're sure the key is present, then do:

```
var result = dict["Apple"](a, b);
```

Or (to show you what actually happens):

```
var func = dict["Apple"];
var result = func(a, b);
```

Otherwise, use `Dictionary.TryGetValue`:

```
Func<int, int, int> func;
if (!dict.TryGetValue("Apple", out func))
{
    // No such function
}

int result = func(a, b);
```

Comment: and when I have that var result = dict["Apple"](a, b); how do I invoke the function?

Comment: That's how you invoke the function. The call to `dict["Apple"]` retrieves the delegate from the dictionary, and invokes it with the `a` and `b` parameters.

Comment: `dict["Apple"](a, b)` will invoke the function if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

Simply retrieve the value by string key and invoke it, passing the appropriate arguments.

```
int numberOfBananas = dict["Banana"](a, b);
```

`Remove` will remove the entry from your dictionary, which is probably not what you're trying to accomplish.

It's worth noting that based on how you are currently adding your functions to your dictionary, your parameters are captured upon registration and the runtime parameters will be ignored.  If you want to provide values at runtime, consider using the following syntax instead.

```
dict.Add("Banana", getNumberofBananas);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to call your function and then remove it:

```
dict["Banana"](a, b);
dict.Remove("Banana");
```

Where `a` and `b` are the arguments to the function you're calling.

I'm not sure how in your code `dict.Remove("...")` returns a function, because documentation says that it returns a `bool` saying whether or not the element was removed.

Comment: I tried this one and it doesn't work. It says "method name expected"

Answer (score 1):

Just like anything else:

```
dict["Banana"](a, b);
```

`Remove`... well... removes the element. All you need is to *read* it - that's what indexers are for. Invoking the delegate is then just about adding the parentheses and arguments.

Comment: Heh... based on your profile image it seems you are experienced enough to answer this question. :)